# Double Exponential integrals in Julia - better precision

Tags: julia, precision, numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate integral with DoubleExponentialFormulas.jl in Julia using the function quadde. However, the relative error I'm getting is ~10^10 in comparing result with Mathematica from the formula: (abs(mathematica-julia)/mathematica - 1)/eps().

I want to make calculation of integral with quadde with better precision. Is there another option than playing with rtol in arguments of quadde?

Maybe there is some better function to integrate with double exponential method?

Comment: That's a strange formula for relative error. Why not `abs(a - b)/abs(b)`? Also, how do you know the accuracy of the Mathematica results?

Answer (score 1):

First, realize that `quadde` takes a desired relative tolerance as an input parameter (`rtol`), which defaults to ≈ `1e-8`.   If you want a smaller error you'll need to pass a smaller tolerance, and it's not clear from your question whether you have done that.

Second, the error will ultimately be limited by the precision.  Mathematica uses arbitrary-precision arithmetic.  By default, in Julia you are probably using double precision (`Float64`), which will limit your attainable accuracy to 14 or 15 digits at best, probably.  However, the DoubleExponentialFormulas package provides an [interface to let you use arbitrary precision](https://github.com/machakann/DoubleExponentialFormulas.jl#optimized-numerical-integrators) if you want greater accuracy (at the expense of greater computational cost).

It's hard to say more without a runnable example of what integral you are trying to compute.